# помогите с доставанием информации из массива с объектами

Tags: javascript, jquery

у меня есть массив с объектами и у каждого объекта в массиве есть свойство index как из всех этих объектов достать значение этого свойства и поместить в переменную?заранее спасибо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```js
var data = [
  ["a", "b"],
  ["c", "d"]
];
data[0].index = 123;
data[1].index = 456;

var newData = data.map(item => item.index);
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Комбинируете `ES5` с `ES6`? :)